# Phone added contact unfindable

Tags: contacts, sync, settings, htc-one-v, troubleshooting

My phone's contacts are synced with my Google and Facebook accounts. Whenever I add a contact through my phone it gets synced to my Google Account. Wonderful... Ok I usually send them a text message to let them know my number and then through my browser I'll add a picture and so forth, all that good stuff. Now under the 'Messages' application on my phone. (Where all my sms activity goes on) I can see this contact with their new picture and our conversation. However If I go to the 'Phonebook' application (the app that manages my phone's contacts) and I do a search for that name, nothing comes up. They are clearly already in my phone since through the Messages app I cannot add them again, but they are not find-able.

What am I doing erroneously??

Comment: Are you sure you have setting to display ALL the contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the People Application

Press the drop down next to phonebook and you can fine tune your contacts better. I had the phone tag checked and not the all contacts checked. I opted to switch to all contacts and have my phone filter out those without phone numbers automatically.

The alternative is to add a phone tag to each contact I want in my phone.